# Laptop Recommendation for Data scientist, with good RAM

Tags: laptop, windows

Looking to buy a new laptop, and needed some options to choose from because I'm totally unaware of laptop characteristics and how they help. Ideally I would like to purchase a laptop
1)Latest Windows Version

2)Can handle R-studio, Python, SAS, SQL data science softwares

3)Also, because I run many simulations I'll need a laptop sith good RAM so can handle many data simultaneously

4. and a good CPU for running quickly the algorithms?

My budget is up to £800 and advise on what should I look will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Asus ZenBook 14 UM425UAZ-KI023T](https://nl.hardware.info/laptops.18/asus-zenbook-14-um425uaz-ki023t.604506) is probably what you are looking for, apart maybe a Framework. It has a fast CPU (R7 5700U), enough RAM (16GB), SSD, Windows 10 (although I am pretty sure it will work better with Linux, most laptops do, and forget about Windows 11, AMD processors work better with Windows 10 and Linux, Windows 11 is just for Alder Lake) and under €800 where I live.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Irsu85 based on what you've send me I did some searching for a higher amount of mine and found this one https://www.currys.co.uk/products/dell-inspiron-14-7415-14-2-in-1-laptop-amd-ryzen-7-512-gb-ssd-blue-10229443.html what do you think?

Comment: Not a fan. Dell customer support is REALLY BAD (source: LTT secret shopper) and it is outside of the budget. Dell is also known for not giving a good upgrade path.